# How to define an array with global scope in SilverStripe?

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables, global, silverstripe

Currently I have the following in _config.php

```
$myConfigArray = array(
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val2'
);
```

However a function in one of my controllers is unable to see the array. It's undefined unless I declare "global $myConfigArray", in which case it's empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use global variables. Don't do it! It may make troubles if another module installed has the same variable for some reason and overwrite your settings.

You can put it in your _config/config.yml where it will be also cached:

```
MyConfig:
  Foo:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

(note the proper intendation of the yml!)

You can access it using Config API, e.g.

```
$foo = Config::inst()->get('MyConfig', 'Foo');
```

Comment: That's a really nice way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In `_config.php` define your variable as `global` before setting it:

```
global $myConfigArray;
$myConfigArray = array(
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2'
);
```

Then in your function declare the global variable before using it:

```
public function myFunction() {
    global $myConfigArray;
    $myConfigArray['key1'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just the standard PHP way then... I had just worked this out myself as your answer appeared :-)